# How can I have MouseUp and MouseDoubleClick events on WPF Datagrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, mvvm-light

Here is the problem. I am using MVVM on a WPF project and using MVVM light. I have a grid in a user control that returns results from a search. I want the users to be able to click on the grid and have the row available for the parent view to use (from a menu) and have it so users can double click on the row and open in a new "window".  Individually I have these items work properly, however I can not get both to work. I am trying to tie 1 command to the MouseUp and another to MouseDoubleClick but the MouseDoubleClick event never gets fired. How can I be able to use the mouseUp and MouseDoubleClick events in a MVVM setup? or any other suggestions to be able to select a row from the datagrid to be available to menu items and to be able to doubleclick on.

Comment: I have figured out part of this. In the WPF Datagrid you can determine if there was a single click or more by checking the MouseLeftButtonDown e.ClickCount. If single click then it is 1 otherwise it is 2 or more. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.mousedoubleclick.aspx for more information. This works in a normal project, but the click count appears off (delayed?) when using MVVM. Maybe someone else can help point in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using MVVMLight the eventtocommand will get you selectionchanged and mousedoubleclicked events.

Comment: I am using the MVVM Light suite however the SelectionChanged and MouseDoubleClicked Events does not get the two selections I want. I have tried the MouseUp + MouseDoubleClick and SelectionChanged + MouseDoubleClick and it only returns the single click and not the double.

Comment: Just to verify you have Selectionchanged on one eventtocommand and Mousedoubleclick on another eventtocommand?

Comment: when using MVVM, this method worked the best. if not using MVVM then I would suggest using the MouseLeftDown and count the clicks. Also note when using the SelectionChanged you must get the SelectedItems list and not use the selecteditem property (caused part of my problem).

Thanks DnnDeveloper

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to have to manually detect a double-click.

```
dblClickTimeOut = null;
row.onmouseup = function() {
    if( dblClickTimeOut == null)
        dblClickTimeOut = setTimeout("dblClickTimeOut = null; selectRow('"+this.id+"');",200);
    else {
        // double-click stuff
    }
}
selectRow = function() {
    // single-click stuff
}
```

Comment: Kolink, is this javascript? I am looking at handling this with a WPF datagrid and not ASP .net. Thanks for the info on the asp .net side.

Comment: Ah, sorry. But the general idea should be the same, that you can't register both MouseUp and MouseDoubleClick events on the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

For those who love short ways (also mvvm friendly!), 
define the interactivity in your xaml-class:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

And in your Grid:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.InputBindings>
     <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding ElementName=xyz, Path=DataContext.MouseDoubleClick}"/>
  </Grid.InputBindings>
  <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseUp">
     <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ElementName=xyz, Path=DataContext.MouseUpEvent}"/>
  </i:EventTrigger>
</Grid>
```

Hope that helps.